# Normed spaces functions?

Tags: functional-analysis

Ive just started to learn about normed spaces and usually the definition requires a vector v to be in the vector space V and thus they define the 2-norm for example, to be the sum of the  root of the sum of the squares from 1 to n. However ive come across some questions where v is a function with a real domain so how it doesnt make sense if i use the sum definition above for the 2-norm since the domain isnt discrete. Would it be integral instead? Same with the sup-norm.

Comment: The $L_2$ norm is $\|f\|_2:=\sqrt{\int_X|f|^2\,d\mu},$ where we are using the Lebesgue integral. There are other norms defined analogously.

Comment: The definition you've seen of the $2$-norm was never supposed to make sense for arbitrary vector spaces; it is specifically about $\mathbb{R}^n$ and $\mathbb{C}^n$, so that you can meaningfully refer to coordinates.